# Pandas: Merge pairs of rows within the same dataframe, while keeping both rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a table of executed trades, where each operation is recorded twice, reported from each side, so that each one is represented by two rows. For some of the trades here are discrepancies between rows, so that the amounts payed and received don't always match. For example maybe one party reports that they payed 100 and received 60, while the counterparty reports that they received 55 and payed 90. So I need to combine it to find the differences between reported numbers (where there are discrepancies).

| Counterparty A | Counterparty B | Amount payed | Amount received | Traders (alphabetical) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Mark | 100 | 60 | John, Mark |
| Mark | John | 65 | 90 | John, Mark |
| Philip | Isaac | 110 | 20 | Isaac, Philip |
| Isaac | Philip | 20 | 100 | Isaac, Philip |

For each row, I would like to add the cells from the opposite side.

Desired result:

| Counterparty A_x | Counterparty B_x | Amount payed_x | Amount received_x | Counterparty A_y | Counterparty B_y | Amount payed_y | Amount received_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **John** | **Mark** | **100** | **60** | *Mark* | *John* | *65* | *90* |
| *Mark* | *John* | *65* | *90* | **John** | **Mark** | **100** | **60** |
| Philip | Isaac | 110 | 20 | Isaac | Philip | 20 | 100 |
| Isaac | Philip | 20 | 100 | Philip | Isaac | 110 | 20 |

This seems that should be *straight-forward*, but I somehow can't get it to work. For example creating one *dataframe* keeping the rows with the first occurence of the shared "`Traders`" value and one dataframe keeping the rows with the second occurence of the shared "`Traders`". And then I tried to merge them onto their "opposite" row in the full dataframe. But didn't manage to get anywhere.

Edit: Forgot to mention the discrepancies between the reported amounts.

Comment: I must be missing something. You seem only to be duplicating columns and changing column labels which is very simple. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I totally forgot to mention that the amounts payed and received that is reported by each side of the trade don't always match. Therefor I can't duplicate the columns (unless I'm missing something basic). I added some information about it in the first paragraph :)

Comment: I thought there were 4 trades not 2! So really you only need 2 rows in the expanded format to cover both the trades with all the information without duplication.

Comment: Yes, in the table I made above there are two trades, each reported twice. But in the full table i'm working with there are a whoooole lot of trades.

And i would like to keep all rows, but expand each of them with the information from the other side of the trade (if possible). I think that would be the most ideal setup for the analysis I would do afterwards. But I might be wrong hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Just define two new columns with the criteria you want. It looks like you want something like this

```
df['Counterparty A_y'] = df['Counterparty B']
df['Counterparty B_y'] = df['Counterparty A']
df['Amount payed_y'] = df['Amount received']
df['Amount recieved_y'] = df['Amount payed']
```

This will keep your old columns and add the new ones. You could then use df.rename to rename your original columns so they have x's, as you have in your desired result.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I totally forgot to mention that these are trades that are reported by the participants. And there are discrepancies between the reportings so that the amounts payed and received don't always match.

For example maybe John reports that he payed 100 and received 60, while Mark reports that he received 55 and payed 90. So I need to combine the rows to find the differences between the reported numbers (where there are discrepancies)

Answer (score 0):

There must be pairs of rows for each trade. These may well be adjacent rows; if not then there must be some column with a tradeID which can be used to sort the rows into adjacent pairs. Then the solution is simply a matter of producing a new data frame with each of the row pairs swapped and combining these into one side-by-side DateFrame. The code below shows the principle - you can modify to suit, re-arrange and re-name columns to produce your required output. I don't think there is a vectorized way to do this so looping is the only way even though it will take some time with a large data size.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], 'b': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]})

num = len(df)-1

df_flip=df.copy()
df_flip.columns = ['c', 'd']

for idx in range(0, num, 2):
    df_flip.iloc[idx,:],df_flip.iloc[idx+1,:]=df.iloc[idx+1,:],df.iloc[idx,:]

combi = pd.concat([df, df_flip], axis = 1)
```

which produces the following with the a, b columns swapped in pairs to c, d:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   3   4
1   3   4   1   2
2   5   6   7   8
3   7   8   5   6
4   9  10  11  12
5  11  12   9  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I do this w/o assuming the 2 rows of each trade are consecutive, also not sorting of the entire df:

```
cols = ['A_x', 'B_x', 'payed_x', 'received_x', 'A_y', 'B_y', 'payed_y', 'received_y']
def concat_rows(d: pd.DataFrame):
    d = d.loc[:, d.columns != 'Traders']
    v1 = list(d.values[0, :])
    v2 = list(d.values[1, :])
    return pd.DataFrame([v1+v2, v2+v1], columns=cols)

df2 = df.groupby('Traders').apply(concat_rows)
```

The definition of the column names is manual here but you can change that as long as it matches the number of expected columns of df2